# grupo de checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

Soy nuevo manejando JavaScript y tengo una vista, que consiste en las salas disponibles según una fecha, la vista me muestra el nombre de la sala con sus respectivos horarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como puedo agrupar las checkbox de tal forma que si marco un check de la sala Chaira, se me desactiven los check de las otras salas. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Buena pregunta, aunque no le parezca a la primera. Estoy evaluando una posible solución.

Comment: DavidE.LunaM. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo más sencillo es usar un framework o librería que soporte programación reactiva; de tal modo que se pueda establecer una propiedad de acuerdo a un suceso esperado. Por ejemplo, en Vue tienes algo como: `:disabled="someRoomChecked"` que lo que hace es escuchar por cambios en la variable "someRoomChecked" para que cuando sea true, ese control se desactive.

Comment: Con jQuery, puedes hacer algo bien sencillo. Agrega una variable "global" que funcione como bandera (si alguna sala fue marcada) y un listener para todos que se encargue de actualizar dicha variable y de desactivar todos los checkboxes **siempre y cuando** no se haya hecho un nuevo click sobre el checkbox marcado (en ese caso se deberá deseleccionar primero).

Comment: cuál es el código que has estado trabajando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo podría ser esta:

Primero, **identifica y agrupa los elementos para poder después seleccionarlos fácilmente**. Por ejemplo, podrías poner a todos los checks una clase sala, y añadir un atributo `data-sala` con el nombre de su sala. Ejemplo:

```
<input class="sala" data-sala="chaira" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 06:00 - 06:59 -->
<input class="sala" data-sala="chaira" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 07:00 - 07:59 -->
...
<input class="sala" data-sala="chaira" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 21:00 - 21:59 -->
...
<input class="sala" data-sala="caqueta" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 06:00 - 06:59 -->
<input class="sala" data-sala="caqueta" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 07:00 - 07:59 -->
...
<input class="sala" data-sala="caqueta" type="checkbox"/> <!-- 21:00 - 21:59 -->
...
```

Ahora puedes añadir a todas las salas un listener, que cuando se marque un checkbox, desmarque el resto de las otras salas:

```
$(".sala").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") {
    var estaSala = $(this).attr("data-sala");
    var checksEstaSala = $('input[data-sala="' + estaSala + '"]');
    $(".sala").not(checksEstaSala).prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

¿Qué hace esto?

En la primera línea definimos un evento `onchange` para todos los checks (los que hemos puesto la clase sala previamente).

Ahora, a partir de la segunda línea, es lo que se va a ejecutar cada vez que el estado el check cambie (lo pongamos a marcado o desmarcado).

Como solo queremos que haga algo si se marca, ponemos la comprobación de `.is(":checked")`;

Después sacamos el nombre de la sala del check que hemos hecho click, el nombre de la sala está en nuestro atributo `data-sala`.

Después, sacamos una lista con todos los checks de esa sala. Por ejemplo si hemos hecho click en un check de chaira, esto seleccionará todos los checks de chaira, pero ojo, no hacemos nada con ellos, simplemente los seleccionamos y lo guardamos en la variable `checksEstaSala`.

Por último seleccionamos todos los checks y quitamos los de esta sala con `.not()`. Así que nos quedan todos los checks menos los de la sala seleccionada. Por último los desmarcamos con `.prop("checked", false);`

- https://api.jquery.com/not/
- https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Muchas gracias.